# When rolling a pair of standard six-sided dice, what is the probability that both dice land on the same number?

Tags: probability, dice

I know that the formula of probability is the following:

***P= FO(favorable outcomes)/PO(possible outcomes)***

What I do not understand is what is the number of PO(possible outcomes) ?

If we take into consideration the order of the dice (i,e **2,1** is a different outcome than **1,2**)then  there are **36 possible scenarios**.

But when we are not interested in the order (in Backgammon game the order is not relevant) there will be only **21 possible scenarios**.

In this particular scenario which should be the probability ?
6/36=**1/6** or 6/21=**2/7** ?

Comment: The outcomes must themselves have equal probability.  Do the 21 outcomes in Backgammon have equal probabilities?

Answer (score 1):

Order is relevant. Think of the two dice as different colours. Then Blue = 1 red = 2 is different from blue = 2 red = 1. You can list all possible outcomes in a 6 by 6 grid.